# how to deploy sharepoint site to internet so i can access my site from internet like eg. www.google.com

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am learning sharepoint server 2010 and now confuse how i can deploy sharepoint site to internet so i can access my site from internet like eg.  www.google.com

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, and at a basic level, you need to first ensure that you [enable Anonymous Access](http://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/sharepoint-2010-anonymous-access/) for your web application. You'll then need to set up DNS for the domain you own to point to your web front end server (or virtual IP if it's load balanced). Then set up the appropraite IIS bindings for the web application, and finally you'll need to extend your web application to an Internet Zone and give it the appropriate domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Not to give a sales pitch, because I just signed up with them but apps4rent has a pretty good deal and all I needed to do was follow their wizard and then go over to my GoDaddy domain account and make one tiny CNAME entry and I was good to go.

However, like JamesLove said, you will want to enable Anonymous Access as well.